# Design of index change, when I push makeindex

Tags: formatting, indexing

Are there somebody who can help me to solve this problem.

I have downloaded a template from this [website](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book).

Before I push on the `makeindex` it looked like this:

[image]

and after it looked like that:

[image]

But when I compile the index and the bibliography the design changes, why does it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6):

Download the complete `zip` file and look for the file `StyleInd.ist`. This file includes the style you missed. Call `makeindex` like this from the console:

```
makeindex <file> -s StyleInd.ist
```